# How to Go to the next page if RadioButton is checked ? in Android programming

Tags: android, android-activity, radio-button

I am new in android . I want to go to the next page if Radio button is checked . I wrote below code but it doesn't work .
what is the problem ?

```
public class second extends Activity {

    public void onCreate (Bundle shamim){


        super.onCreate(shamim);

        setContentView(R.layout.second);


        findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);

        RadioButton radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);


        findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        RadioButton radioButton2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);


        if (radioButton1.isChecked()) {

            startActivity(new Intent(second.this,third.class));

             else { (radioButton2.isChecked()) {


                startActivity(new Intent(second.this,MyActivity.class));

            }

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Remove findViewById(R.id.radioButton1); and findViewById(R.id.radioButton2); as these are not required.

Comment: use radiobutton.setOnCheckedChangeListerner.

Answer (score 1):

`isChecked()` will only give you the current state of the button. It won't inform you when the state has changed (which by default is not checked), so your code isn't set up to react to when a user actually clicks the button.

Instead of calling `isChecked`, you probably want to set a listener on each button to know when either is clicked, so that you can respond appropriately:

```
radioButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if (isChecked)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(second.this,third.class));
        }
    }
}

radioButton2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if (isChecked)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(second.this,MyActivity.class));
        }
    }
}
```